# PHP $_SESSION not working with Fancybox AJAX cal

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

I'm having a real battle here and was really hoping somebody could help out.  I was up late last night trying every solution google offered but still not had success.

MY site has a list on ingredients which i'd like to add to a recipe.

To process for this is:

1. Click "add to recipe".  Which opens a fancybox iframe containing jquery UI tabbed content from allows users to enter a measurement in grams.
2. From here the user clicks "add" and the fancybox content makes an AJAX call (having built the data string which is created fine)..
3. THe PHP file called by AJAX simply cast the value passed to int (of food id and weight) and stores it in the:

   `$_SESSION['recipe'][] = array('id' => $id , 'weight' => $weight);`
4. Once complete the fancybox closes and the div on the starting page (step one) which contains the calorie information for the recipe should reload and update.

All steps seem to work except 3.

Whenever I try to `vardump` the session it's empty.

I've started session on each page, i.e. step 1, the the fancybox page, then the ajax called page.

I'm at a total loss.

My AJAX call at step 3 is:

```
    $(document).on('click', '.add-food-button', function () {
    var weight = $("input#grams").val();  
    var id = $("input#ingredientid").val();  
    //var sez = $("input#sez").val();  

    var dataString = 'g='+ weight +'&id=' + id ; //+ "&sid=" + sez; 

    if (weight > 0)
    {

        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",  
          url: "../ajax/add-ingredient-to-recipe.php?"+dataString,  
          dataType: "html",
          data: dataString,  
            success: function (msg) {


                frames.top.$.fancybox.close(true);
                frames.top.$('#calorie-table').load('./views/recipe-calorie-chart.tmp.php');

            }

        });



    }else{
          $('#grams').addClass('errorInput');
          $('#weight-label').addClass('errorLabel');
    }

});
```

and the php file called (Step 4) is:

```
<?php

session_start();

include('../includes/config.inc.php');

if (isset($_GET['weight']) && $_GET['id'])
{   
    $weight = (int) $_GET['weight'];
    $id = (int) $_GET['id'];
    $_SESSION['recipe'][] = array('id' => $id,'weight' => $weight);



}

?>
```

I've read about passing a session ID through the AJAX as the AJAX call could be generating a new session and i actually need to be using the one already open.  If that is the case how do I do that?

Any advice would be brilliant!

Comment: where you are accessing $_SESSION['recipe']  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you check you ajax call then you will find that you are passing "g" & "id" variable in query string. But in php file you are checking that "weight" && "id". So this condition will not true and session will never set. so you are getting the blank session value.

updated ajax call

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",  
      url: "../ajax/add-ingredient-to-recipe.php?"+dataString,  
      dataType: "html",           
        success: function (msg) {


            frames.top.$.fancybox.close(true);
            frames.top.$('#calorie-table').load('./views/recipe-calorie-chart.tmp.php');

        }

    });
```

Updated php code

```
    session_start();

include('../includes/config.inc.php');

if (isset($_GET['g']) && $_GET['id'])
{   
    $weight = (int) $_GET['g'];
    $id = (int) $_GET['id'];
    $_SESSION['recipe'][] = array('id' => $id,'weight' => $weight);



}
```